# Javascript - Accessing element values? DOM tree?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with multiple text input fields and sub-forms. Is there a way to access everything based on how it appears in the DOM tree?

In other words, if I have

```
<div id="formContent">
    <input type="text" value="some stuff" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" value="some stuff" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" value="some stuff" />
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
            <input type="text" value="some sub-stuff" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can I access those in the order they appear and assign them values?

**EDIT:** The reason I ask is because I will be allowing people to add and remove the main and sub-forms, so I can't assign them id's. I also won't know how many sub-options each form will have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming they're wrapped in a `<form>` tag (which we can't see here), you can access them via the `elements[]` array.  This does the job when you don't have `id` attributes to work with via `getElementById()`

```
// Supply the correct index - 0 assumes this is the first form on the page...
var yourForm = document.forms[0];

// Loop over the form elements
for (var i=0; i < yourForm.elements.length; i++) {
  yourForm.elements[i].value = "some new value";
}
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/DLrCY/

Comment: Not sure the order match the order they appear.. have you tested it?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard by my experience and all documentation I've read they're supposed to be in order.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I just tested it successfully in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLrCY/

Comment: Thanks. How do I get the child elements of the form elements though? I believe I tried `document.forms[0].elements[0].elements[0]` and `document.forms[0].elements[0].forms[0].elements[0]`. I'm sure those both seem pretty dumb to anyone who knows a thing or two about javascript. I didn't try `document.forms[0].elements[0][0]` but I doubt that would work either.

Comment: Oh. I see now that `document.forms[0].elements[]` will grab ALL the elements inside the form, regardless of whether they are inside another element.

Comment: @user828584 You've got it.  `elements[]` lists them all in order, without any kind of nesting.

Comment: OK, well I updated the OP. Like I said, I need to be able to get the elements based on how they are nested because I can't be sure how many there will be in each.

Comment: @user828584 Just to be clear, they do get listed in the exact order as they have been nested, but you cannot tell how many exist in each `<ul>` group

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can get a list of children of the `div` element with id `formContent`, then iterate through that array.

```
var div = document.getElementById("formContent");
for(var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; i++) {
    // do something with this element;
}
```

Note that this is going to return ALL of the direct children of the div (including the lists), so you'll need to do some extra processing and some additional traversal to handle those and get the input elements contained within them.

Comment: Good and correct idea, but it will fail to reach the elements inside the lists.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I realised that myself after I'd posted, and updated the answer to address that.

Comment: Well, you can have recursive function but Michael way is better by all means now that it's proved to keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the solution in JQuery it would be like that.

```
$('div > input[type=text]').each(function(){
  this.value = "some new value";
});
```

---

**Edit**

If you need the solution in simple JS you will be doing like this.

```
var yourForm = document.forms[0];

// Loop over the form elements
for (var i=0; i < yourForm.elements.length; i++) {
  if( /^text/.test( els[j].type ) ){// check for text boxes
    yourForm.elements.value = "new Value";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var get_div = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

 for( var i=0; i<get_div.length; i++ )// total no of child including all node ex:text,element
  {
 var child_length=get_div[i].childNodes.length;    // to get child of particular node. 
 for( j=0; j<child_length; j++ )
     {
       some code;;;
     }
  }
```